# Destroy script for provisioning

Tags: ruby, installer

Script intended to remove Vault & Consul setup before run re-provision them on server.

This is my first Ruby script, so will be perfect to see my mistakes here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/ssh'

$me = File.basename(__FILE__)

print "\n[#{$me}] Vault & Consul DESTROY started on the #{$HOST}.\n"

if not ARGV.empty? then
    $HOST = ARGV[0]
    puts "\n[#{$me}] Working on the #{$HOST}"
else
    puts "[#{$me}] ERROR: host to destroy must be in first argument. Exit."
    exit 1
end

$USER = 'knife';
$RSA_KEY = 'ssh/id_rsa';

$HOMES = {
        "vault" => "/opt/vault/",
        "consul" => "/opt/consul/"
        }

if File.exist?($RSA_KEY) then
    File.chmod(0600, $RSA_KEY)
else
    puts "[#{$me}] ERROR: no RSA file #{$RSA_KEY} found. Exit."
    exit 1
end


def service_check(service)
    Net::SSH.start($HOST, $USER, :keys => $RSA_KEY) do |ssh|
        process_status = ssh.exec!("sudo ps aux | grep #{service} | grep -v grep | wc -l")
        return process_status
    end
end


def service_delete(service_path)
        Net::SSH.start($HOST, $USER, :keys => $RSA_KEY) do |ssh|
        res = ssh.exec!("if test -d #{service_path}; then 
                            ls -l #{service_path}
                        else
                            echo \"ERROR: no #{service_path} directory found. Exit.\"
                            exit 1
                        fi; echo $?")
        puts res
    end
end


def service_stop(service)
    Net::SSH.start($HOST, $USER, :keys => $RSA_KEY) do |ssh|
        if ssh.exec!("sudo service #{service} stop; echo $?") then
            puts "\nService #{service} stopped"
        else
            puts "ERROR during #{service} stop"
        end
    end
end


def service_cleanup(service)

    _initdir = '/etc/init.d'
    _upstartdir = '/etc/init'
    _logdir = '/var/log'
    _bindir = '/usr/local/bin'

    Net::SSH.start($HOST, $USER, :keys => $RSA_KEY) do |ssh|
        cleaned = ssh.exec!("
            # /etc/init.d/vault
            if test -e #{_initdir}/#{service}; then
                sudo ls -l #{_initdir}/#{service}
            else
                echo \"File #{_initdir}/#{service} not found, skip\"
            fi

            # /etc/init/vault
            if test -e #{_upstartdir}/#{service}; then
                sudo ls -l #{_upstartdir}/#{service}
            else
                echo \"File #{_initdir}/#{service} not found, skip\"
            fi

            # /var/log/vault
            if test -e #{_logdir}/#{service}.log; then
                sudo ls -l #{_logdir}/#{service}.log
            else
                echo \"File #{_initdir}/#{service} not found, skip\"
            fi

            # /usr/local/bin/vault
            if test -e #{_bindir}/#{service}; then
                sudo ls -l #{_bindir}/#{service}
            else
                echo \"File #{_initdir}/#{service} not found, skip\"
            fi

            ")
        puts cleaned
    end
end

def service_destroy(service)
    # 1 if service up and running
    # 0 otherwise
    s_status = service_check(service)

    if s_status.to_i == 1
        puts "Stopping #{service} on the #{$HOST}"
        service_stop(service)
    else
        puts "\nService #{service} already stopped: #{service_check(service)}"
    end

    print "\nRemoving #{service} data in #{$HOMES[service]}...\n\n"
    service_delete($HOMES[service])

    print "\nCleaning up after service.\n\n"
    service_cleanup(service)

end

for service in $HOMES.each_key
    service_destroy(service)
end
```

And it's execution:

> ```
> $ ./scripts/destroy.rb setevoy.vault.local
>
> [destroy.rb] Vault & Consul DESTROY started on the $HOST.
>
> [destroy.rb] Working on the setevoy.vault.local
>
> Service vault already stopped: 0
>
> Removing vault data in /opt/vault/...
>
> total 8
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:46 conf.d
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:38 data
> 0
>
> Cleaning up after service.
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 919 Feb 12 13:38 /etc/init.d/vault
> File /etc/init.d/vault not found, skip
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2687 Feb 15 13:44 /var/log/vault.log
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 33614224 Feb 12 13:35 /usr/local/bin/vault
>
> Service consul already stopped: 0
>
> Removing consul data in /opt/consul/...
>
> total 12
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:46 conf.d
> drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:38 data
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:46 web-ui
> 0
>
> Cleaning up after service.
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 935 Feb 12 13:38 /etc/init.d/consul
> File /etc/init.d/consul not found, skip
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19883 Feb 15 15:55 /var/log/consul.log
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 20417720 Jan 14 21:33 /usr/local/bin/consul
> ```

Comment: Be ready for "Ruby should be indented with 2 spaces, not 4" instead of pointing at "mistakes".

Comment: @Nakilon That's appreciated too :-) I came to Ruby from Python, so - yeah - I used for 4 spaces + 2 lines before `def`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Kernel#abort`:

   ```
   puts "[#{$me}] ERROR: host to destroy must be in first argument. Exit."
   exit 1
   ```

   will behave the same as:

   ```
   abort "[#{$me}] ERROR: host to destroy must be in first argument. Exit."
   ```
2. Since it's a simple standalone script and not a space shuttle, you did OK that didn't use OOP (`class`, `module`), but methods defined in the way you did can't access variables just outside, so you had to use either global variables (`$`) or constants (upper case in identifier name) when possible (seems to be your case, so you could omit the dollar sign) to make them accessible from methods (`def`).
   You could use `lambda`s to resolve the scope issue and have some syntax sugar as a free bonus:

   ```
   service_destroy = lambda do |service|
     # ...
   end

   homes.keys.each(&service_destroy)
   ```