# Ruby backup/restore for provisioning

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, ruby, shell, ssh

This is my second Ruby coding attempt. Also - this is my first OOP usage in Ruby.

I'm using `if __FILE__ == $0` form here - same as it is in Python because it's really comfortably as for me. Is there is any objections/restrictions for such usage?

Any other tips/links about this code appreciated as well.

Script intended to create Consul raft-database backup before run `destroy.rb` from my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120056/destroy-script-for-provisioning) review, or restore database after provisioning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/ssh'

$me = File.basename(__FILE__)

class CheckIn

    USER = 'knife';
    RSA_KEY = 'ssh/id_rsa';

    def initialize(host)

        @@host = host;

        if File.exist?(RSA_KEY) then
            File.chmod(0600, RSA_KEY);
        else
            abort "[#{$me}] ERROR: no RSA file #{RSA_KEY} found. Exit.\n";
        end

    end
end


class BackupRestore < CheckIn

    def backup()

        _consul_raft_db = '/opt/consul/data/raft/raft.db'
        _root_backup_dir = '/root/vaul_devops_kdbx/backups'
        _raft_backup_file = "#{Time.now.strftime("%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%y")}_bkp_raft.db"

        Net::SSH.start(@@host, USER, :keys => RSA_KEY) do |ssh|

            backuped = ssh.exec!("

            if test -e #{_consul_raft_db}; then
                echo \"\"
                echo \"OK: Consul DB found - #{_consul_raft_db}.\"
                echo \"\"
            else
                echo \"ERROR: no #{_consul_raft_db} file found. Exit.\"
                exit 1
            fi

            if sudo [ -d #{_root_backup_dir} ]; then
                echo \"OK: #{_root_backup_dir} found.\"
                echo \"\"
            else
                echo \"ERROR: no #{_root_backup_dir} directory found. Exit.\"
                exit 1
            fi

            if sudo cp #{_consul_raft_db} #{_root_backup_dir}/#{_raft_backup_file}; then
                echo \"OK: backup created:\"
                echo \"\"
                sudo ls -l #{_root_backup_dir}/#{_raft_backup_file}
                echo \"\"
                echo \"All backups present on the #{@@host} in the #{_root_backup_dir}:\"
                echo \"\"
                sudo ls -l #{_root_backup_dir}
                echo \"\"
            else
                echo \"\"
                echo \"ERROR: can not complete backup from #{_consul_raft_db} to #{_root_backup_dir}/#{_raft_backup_file}. Exit.\"
                exit 1
            fi

            ")

            puts backuped

        end
    end

    def restore()

        puts "\nRestore will be here\n\n"

    end

end


if __FILE__ == $0

    puts "\n[#{$me}] Consul backup/restore started.\n"

    if ARGV.length == 2 and (ARGV[1] == 'backup' or ARGV[1] == 'restore')
        _host = ARGV[0]
        _mode = ARGV[1]

        puts "\n[#{$me}] Working on the #{_host} in #{_mode} mode.";

        run = BackupRestore.new(_host)
        run.send(_mode)
    else
        abort "\n[#{$me}] ERROR: HOST must be specified as first argument and MODE (backup or restore) - as second one. Exit..\n"
    end

    puts "[#{$me}] Consul backup/restore finished.\n\n"

end
```

And it's execution - `backup`:

> ```
> $ ./scripts/backup.rb setevoy.vault.local backup
>
> [backup.rb] Consul backup/restore started.
>
> [backup.rb] Working on the setevoy.vault.local in backup mode.
>
> OK: Consul DB found - /opt/consul/data/raft/raft.db.
>
> OK: /root/vaul_devops_kdbx/backups found.
>
> OK: backup created:
>
> -rw------- 1 root root 2097152 Feb 17 16:11 /root/vaul_devops_kdbx/backups/16_11_57_17_02_16_bkp_raft.db
>
> All backups present on the setevoy.vault.local in the /root/vaul_devops_kdbx/backups:
>
> total 20248
> -rw------- 1 root root 1048576 Feb 17 14:21 14_21_50_17_02_16_bkp_raft.db
> [...[
> -rw------- 1 root root 2097152 Feb 17 16:11 16_11_57_17_02_16_bkp_raft.db
>
> [backup.rb] Consul backup/restore finished.
> ```

and "`restore`":

> ```
> $ ./scripts/backup.rb setevoy.vault.local restore
>
> [backup.rb] Consul backup/restore started.
>
> [backup.rb] Working on the setevoy.vault.local in restore mode.
>
> Restore will be here
>
> [backup.rb] Consul backup/restore finished.
> ```

Comment: Why the rush in accepting? I feel honored that you think nobody can do a better job than me, but rest assured: you are wrong ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Just was fascinated with your answer :-) If the first point with `;` - just stupid habit and few others - came here from my previous Python experience (not to big, although) - every other one really sobered me up.
Will see, what others thinking :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have time for a proper review, so I'll stick to the more obvious points:

- Indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces, not 4.
- Not only is your use of semicolons inconsistent (sometimes you use them, sometimes you don't), every single one of those you *do* have is superfluous. Leave them out. You can use either newline or semicolon as "statement" separator, using both is not necessary.
- The same applies to your usage of the `then` keyword: sometimes you use it, sometimes you don't, and all uses are superfluous. Leave them out. You can use either the `then` keyword or a "statement" separator (newline or semicolon) to separate the condition from the `then` body, using both is not necessary.
- There is a large number of superfluous newlines. You'd generally have one *before* a new class, module or method definition, but not *within* – if your method is so long that it needs to be broken down in sections, consider refactoring it.
- You can save yourself a lot of trouble escaping all the double quotes in the giant string by using either some other delimiter (e.g. `backuped = ssh.exec!(%Q[ … ]`) or a heredoc.
- Leave out empty parameter lists, e.g. `def backup` instead of `def backup()`.
- By convention, variable names that start with an underscore `_` are used for variables that are ignored. So, you would really only use them for multiple assignment or unused block parameters. In fact, it is more than just a convention: Ruby will warn you about unused local variables, but these warnings are suppressed for variables starting with an underscore, *because* they are intended as "ignored" variables.
- You should prefer `public_send` over `send`. The latter circumvents access protection, the former honors it.
- Prefer `&&`/`||` over `and`/`or`. The former actually have the precedence you would expect from them, the latter don't.
- For the string inside the interpolation within your `raft_backup_file` string, you could use single quotes instead of double quotes. Personally, I *always* use single quotes unless I actually *need* to do interpolation or use escape sequences (or there is a single quote *in* the string). This makes it clear just when looking at the beginning of the string whether or not there is going to be interpolation.

Note that since you use a class variable to store part of your state (`@@host`), it is impossible to create more than one instance of your class, so it doesn't make sense to have a class at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/ssh'

$me = File.basename(__FILE__)

class CheckIn
  USER = 'knife'
  RSA_KEY = 'ssh/id_rsa'

  def initialize(host)
    @@host = host

    if File.exist?(RSA_KEY)
      File.chmod(0600, RSA_KEY)
    else
      abort "[#$me] ERROR: no RSA file #{RSA_KEY} found. Exit.\n"
    end
  end
end

class BackupRestore < CheckIn
  def backup
    consul_raft_db = '/opt/consul/data/raft/raft.db'
    root_backup_dir = '/root/vaul_devops_kdbx/backups'
    raft_backup_file = "#{Time.now.strftime('%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%y')}_bkp_raft.db"

    Net::SSH.start(@@host, USER, keys: RSA_KEY) do |ssh|
      backuped = ssh.exec!(%Q[
        if test -e #{consul_raft_db}; then
            echo ""
            echo "OK: Consul DB found - #{consul_raft_db}."
            echo ""
        else
            echo "ERROR: no #{consul_raft_db} file found. Exit."
            exit 1
        fi

        if sudo [ -d #{root_backup_dir} ]; then
            echo "OK: #{root_backup_dir} found."
            echo ""
        else
            echo "ERROR: no #{root_backup_dir} directory found. Exit."
            exit 1
        fi

        if sudo cp #{consul_raft_db} #{root_backup_dir}/#{raft_backup_file}; then
            echo "OK: backup created:"
            echo ""
            sudo ls -l #{root_backup_dir}/#{raft_backup_file}
            echo ""
            echo "All backups present on the #@@host in the #{root_backup_dir}:"
            echo ""
            sudo ls -l #{root_backup_dir}
            echo ""
        else
            echo ""
            echo "ERROR: can not complete backup from #{consul_raft_db} to #{root_backup_dir}/#{raft_backup_file}. Exit."
            exit 1
        fi
      ])

      puts backuped
    end
  end

  def restore
    puts "\nRestore will be here\n\n"
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "\n[#$me] Consul backup/restore started.\n"

  if ARGV.length == 2 && (ARGV[1] == 'backup' || ARGV[1] == 'restore')
    host = ARGV[0]
    mode = ARGV[1]

    puts "\n[#$me] Working on the #{host} in #{mode} mode."

    run = BackupRestore.new(host)
    run.public_send(mode)
  else
    abort "\n[#$me] ERROR: HOST must be specified as first argument and MODE (backup or restore) - as second one. Exit..\n"
  end

  puts "[#$me] Consul backup/restore finished.\n\n"
end
```

Comment: Spot on, except: there's no improper quoting for that string. The syntax highlighting is not interpolation-aware, making it _look_ broken.

Comment: Hah. You're right. Apparently, not only is SO's syntax highlighter crappy, my brain's is, too. I removed that section.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Just came to work and started to edit my script - thanks for your answer :-) One more Q, please: > You'd generally have one before a new class, module or method definition, but not within // why it looks so bad for you - add newlines before/after variables definitions, before/after loops, if/else, methods? As for me - it makes the code more readable... Correct me, please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @setevoy It's personal preference, but consider this: the more blank lines you have, the less code you can see on screen at once, and thus the less context you have in your vision. If a method is getting longer than a certain limit (which is not a hard number, but consider half a screen) you should probably break it up into smaller methods with logical and helpful names, and clear, targeted goals.

Comment: I said that it's a general rule, and as you can see in my answer, I *did* sprinkle some whitespace around for better readability. But other than that, what Phrogz said.